# How to copy an instance of the Ruby Fiddle struct?

Tags: ruby, fiddle

It's not obvious how to copy an instance of the Fiddle struct. I found an ugly solution using the `Fiddle::Pointer` like this.

```
require 'fiddle/import'

X = Fiddle::Importer.struct [
  'int a',
  'int b',
]

x = X.malloc
x.a = 1
x.b = 2

x2 = X.malloc
Fiddle::Pointer.new(x2.to_i)[0, X.size] = x.to_ptr.to_s
x2.b = 3
p [x.b, x2.b]
```

Is there a better way of doing this? One other way I thought of was using the `[]=` operator of the super class(`Fiddle::Pointer`) of the `x2.to_ptr`, but it was worse than the above solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class returned by `Fiddle::Importer.struct` implements `[]` and `[]=` to retrieve and set the struct members by name:

```
x['a'] #=> 1
x['b'] #=> 2
```

However, when called with 2 arguments, these methods behave like their `Fiddle::Pointer` counterparts and get / set the raw binary data:

```
x[0, 4] #=> "\x01\x00\x00\x00"   <- a's binary data
x[4, 4] #=> "\x02\x00\x00\x00"   <- b's binary data

x[4, 4] = [-5].pack('l') #=> "\xFB\xFF\xFF\xFF"
x.b #=> -5
```

To copy `x`'s entire data to `x2`:

```
x2[0, X.size] = x[0, X.size]

x2.a #=> 1
x2.b #=> 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before but failed because I was using Ruby 2.7. In Ruby 3.2, it works fine. I confirmed this feature was added in Ruby 3.0.0. It would be great if you mention this for future readers.